# Rails: how to use scope inside has_many block in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 4 I am using:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :request_attendances, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :attending_request_attendances, -> {
    where("data->>'rsvp_completed' = 'true'")
      .where("data->>'is_coming' = 'true'")
  }, class_name: 'RequestAttendance'

end
```

In my Tickets model

And

```
class RequestAttendance < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :tickets, inverse_of: :request_attendances

  scope :is_coming, -> { where("data->>'is_coming' = 'true'")}
  scope :rsvp_completed, -> { where("data->>'rsvp_completed' = 'true'")}

end
```

In my RequestAttendance model

I would like to do something like this

```
has_many :attending_request_attendances, -> {
  :is_coming
  :rsvp_completed
}, class_name: 'RequestAttendance'
```

To reuse the scope I have created in my RequestAttendance model.

Is something like this possible, at the moment it does not work, giving me the following error:

> undefined method `except' for :rsvp_completed:Symbol

If I add a where to the has_many block like this:

```
has_many :attending_request_attendances, -> {
  :is_coming
  :rsvp_completed
  where("data->>'rsvp_completed' = 'true'")
}, class_name: 'RequestAttendance'
```

It does not error, however it also does not use the scope clauses either.

Comment: Can you try this: `has_many :attending_request_attendances, -> { is_coming. rsvp_completed }, class_name: 'RequestAttendance'`

Comment: Thanks @ThanhHuynh this works well.

Comment: @ThanhHuynh Perhaps you could add it as an answer as it may be a useful pattern for others looking for a similar solution

Comment: Ok, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain scopes together inside an association like this:

```
has_many :attending_request_attendances, -> { 
  is_coming.rsvp_completed 
}, class_name: 'RequestAttendance'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the below code in RequestAttendance model

```
scope :is_coming, -> { where("data->>'is_coming' = 'true'")}
scope :rsvp_completed, -> { where("data->>'rsvp_completed' = 'true'")}
```

if you use the below code in Tickets Model

```
class Tickets < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :RequestAttendance 
end
```

scopes are available to has_many associations so it will fetch all the records with is_coming' = 'true' and "data->>'rsvp_completed' = 'true'"

You can fetch it using object tickets.requestAttendance.is_coming.rsvp_completed

Is it your expectation or If I misunderstood pls explain